# Larger CSS font sizes in QTextEdit-based editor

Tags: python, css, pyqt4, pyside, rich-text-editor

We are making a `QTextEdit`-based editor.
We are using `QtGui.QComboBox` in `QtGui.QTextEdit` for selecting font sizes.
The CSS sizes we are using are: `small`, `normal`, `large`, `x-large` and `xx-large`.
The largest size winds up being about 24 points.
Is there any way to make it 48 points?
(While keeping the ability to zoom with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-Mouse wheel.)

Comment: Use `pt` or `px` instead of the relative CSS font sizes.

Comment: Then CTRL + mouse wheel roll doesn't zoom though.

Answer (score 3):

The [CSS font-size property](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/richtext-html-subset.html#css-properties) supports either an absolute size (specified in points or pixels), or a named relative size ("small", "medium", "large", "x-large", or "xx-large").

The relative sizes are relative to the document font size - which means the font size set on the `body` tag for rich-text documents. If the document font size has not been set explicitly, it will be inherited from the default font for the widget (if it has one), or the application default font.

So if the document font has been set to 10pt:

```
font = QFont(self.widget.font())
font.setPointSize(10)
widget.setFont(font)
```

Then the relative fonts will be calculated as follows:

- `small`:  0.8 * 10 = 8pt
- `medium`: 1.0 * 10 = 10pt
- `large`: 1.2 * 10 = 12pt
- `x-large`: 1.5 * 10 = 15pt
- `xx-large`: 2.0 * 10 = 20pt

This means that the only way to get `xx-large` to be 48pt would be to set the document font-size to 24pt (which is pretty useless, but there it is).

Note that zooming works by changing the document font-size. So setting an absolute font-size on a block of text will prevent it being zoomed.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this point.
Unfortunately this still leaves us without the ability to make larger fonts.

Is it possible to redefine the stylesheet to increase the multipliers?
Or perhaps we can define more stylesheets?
Or is there any other way to change the font sizes without sacrificing the ability to zoom the document?

Comment: @VeetVivarto. The multipliers are hard-coded into the `QTextCharFormat` implementation, which is also used for formatting `big`, `small`, `h1`, `h2`, etc html tags. So its hard to see a way around this, particularly if you want document zooming as well. You're really coming up against the same problems that web-page designers have - only it's even worse, because `QTextEdit` only supports a limited subset of html and css. What sort of editor are you building? Have you considered using [QScintilla](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/qscintilla/intro) instead?